# Replace not working

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, notepad++

I have a text-file of data in key-value pairs that I have managed to convert to a format where the key-value pairs are all separated by an underscore between them, and the key is separated from the value by a colon. I thought this format would be useful for keeping spaces intact within the data. Here's an example with the data substituted for `~~~~~~~`s.

```
_ID:~~~_NAME:~~~~~_DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_TYPE2:~~~~~~ ...etc
```

I want to convert this to a MySQL script to insert the data into a table. My problem is there are nullable fields that aren't included in every record. e.g. A record has a `_TYPE1:` and may or may not have a `_TYPE2:`

```
... _DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_TYPE2:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~ ...
... _DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~ ...
... _DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~ ...
... _DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_TYPE2:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~ ...
... _DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~ ...
```

I thought to fix this by inserting `_TYPE2:` after every `_TYPE1` without a `_TYPE2:`. Since there are only a few different possible types, I managed to select the `_` after each `_TYPE1:~~~~~~` without a `TYPE2:` following it. I used the following regex, where `egtype` is one example of a possible type:

```
(?<=_TYPE1:egtype)_(?!TYPE2:)
```

At this point, all I have to do is replace that `_` with `_TYPE2:_` and every field is present in every line, which makes it easy to convert every row to a MySQL insert statement! Unfortunately, Notepad++ is not replacing it when I click the Replace button. I'm not sure why.

Does anyone know why it wouldn't replace an `_` with `_TYPE2:_` using that particular regex? Or does anyone have any other suggestions on how to turn all this data into a MySQL insert script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex

To do what you want, try this:

Find:

```
_TYPE1:[^_]+\K(?!.*_TYPE2)
```

Replace:

```
_TYPE2:
```

You can test it with your sample data and have it explained [here](http://regex101.com/r/nU7oJ3).

---

### Python Script plugin

As a side note, I don't think it's possible to convert your data into SQL insert statements with the use of one and only one regular expression, and while I see what you are trying to do by adding fake TYPE2, I don't think it is your best option.

So, my suggestion is to use Notepad++'s Python Script plugin.

1. Install Python Script plugin, from Plugin Manager or from the [official website](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).
2. Then go to Plugins > Python Script > New Script. Choose a filename for your new file (eg sql_insert.py) and copy the code that follows.
3. Run Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > sql_insert.py and a new tab will show up the desired result.

#### Script:

```py
columns = [[]]
values = [[]]
current_line = 0

def insert(line, match):
    global current_line
    if line > current_line:
        current_line += 1
        columns.append([])
        values.append([])
    if match:
        i = 0
        for m in match.groups():
            if i % 2 == 0:
                columns[line].append(m)
            else:
                values[line].append(m)
            i += 1

editor.pysearch("_([A-Z0-9]+):([^_\n]+)", insert)

notepad.new()
for line in range(len(columns)):
    editor.addText("INSERT INTO table (" + ",".join(columns[line]) + ") values (" + ",".join(values[line]) +");\n")
```

Note: I'm still learning Python and I've a feeling that this one could be written in a better way. Feel free to edit my answer or drop a comment if you can suggest improvements!

#### Example input:

```
_ID:~~~_NAME:~~~~~_DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_TYPE2:~~~~~~
_ID:~~~_NAME:~~~~~_DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_TYPE2:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~
_ID:~~~_NAME:~~~~~_DESCRIPTION:~~~~~~_TYPE1:~~~~~~_ADDRESS:~~~~~~~
```

#### Example output:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,TYPE1,TYPE2) values (~~~,~~~~~,~~~~~~~,~~~~~~,~~~~~~);
INSERT INTO table (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,TYPE1,TYPE2,ADDRESS) values (~~~,~~~~~,~~~~~~,~~~~~~,~~~~~~,~~~~~~~);
INSERT INTO table (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,TYPE1,ADDRESS) values (~~~,~~~~~,~~~~~~,~~~~~~,~~~~~~~);
```

Comment: Your regex expression worked, but Notepad++ wouldn't let me replace. Maybe it's a bug in my install, or something.

Your Python script, however, was amazing. I think I'm going to have to learn Python. I was going to do something similar in PHP if I couldn't figure out the regex, but this worked amazing! I just had to add `'` around the data, then use replace to get rid of the newlines before the `);` and it worked beautifully. Thanks!

`editor.addText("INSERT INTO table (" + ",".join(columns[line]) + ") values ('" + ",".join(values[line]) +"');\n")`

Comment: I'm happy that the script helped :) But I don't understand why you can't replace! Is there an error message or something? Do you have the latest Notepad++ version? If no, try to update, and be sure that it's at least higher than version 6.0.

Comment: Actually, when I went to try it again, I found something weird. The `Replace` button would't work for one record at a time, but the `Replace All` button works on all of them. So my first expression did work as well, although yours is better because it selects all of them without having to use each individual type, like mine. It's still weird that my `Replace` button didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

try searching for `(_TYPE1:)(\S\S\S\S\S\S)(_ADDRESS:)`
and replacing with `\1\2_TYPE2:~~~~~~\3`
i tested in notepad++ with your data and it works
don't forget to change the Search Mode to regular expression.
to turn it into an INSERT script just keep using regular expression like i did above, and bracket which ever field you want and then replace with a \number whichever field and move them around it should be pretty simple manual labor, have fun.
for example search for your whole line here i am only doing DESCRIPTION,TYPE1,and TYPE2
search for using regular expression
  `(_DESCRIPTION)(:)(\S\S\S\S\S\S)(_TYPE1)(:)(\S\S\S\S\S\S)(_TYPE2)(:)(\S\S\S\S\S\S)`
then replace with something like 
  `INSERT INTO table1\(desc,type1,type2\)values\('\3','\6','\9'\);` (in notepad++)

Comment: i tried your expression, it works on finding but it's not replacing at all for some reason, might be a bug maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a once-off problem then a two step process would work. First step would add a `_TYPE2:SomeDefaultValue` to every line. Step two would remove it from lines where it was not needed.

Step 1: Find what: `$`, Replace with: `_TYPE2:xxx`

Step 2: Find what: `(_TYPE2:.*)_TYPE2:xxx$`, Replace with: `\1`

In both steps select "regular expression" and un-select "dot matches newline". Also change `xxx` to your default value.